# Using Nokogiri to scrape itemprop data

Tags: ruby

I have a div which looks like the following and I am trying to scrape the itemprop datetime data but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2019-03-28T19:00:00">
  Thursday, March 28, 2019
</time>
```

The script below pulls the text for the date just fine (i.e., . Thursday, March 28, 2019), but the time selector throws this error.

```
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've searched Stackoverflow, and I've tried to map the time data but nothing works.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

my_local_filename = "C:/data-hold-classes/Santa Fe College" + ".html"

data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(my_local_filename), "r")

classes = data.css(".col-xs-7")

classes.each do |item|

class  = item.at_css("a b").text.strip #=> All details
date = item.at_css("a > div > time").text.strip #==> Thursday, March 28, 2019

#time = item.at_css("a datetime").text.strip  #==> 


puts class
puts date
#puts time

puts " "
end
```

My goal is to pull the datetime portion of the div so I can format it as time (e.g., 8:00PM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `item.at_css("a > div > time")` returns an element `time`.

`a > div > time` is a nested path to get that element. Now, you wanna get `time`, an attribute, not html element, so path `a datetime` will not return anything (cause we have no datetime element).

You can get date by using:

```
item.at_css("a > div > time")["datetime"].strip
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you so much !